# I want send mail alert if kafka broker (localhost:9092) goes down

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am using below method to send the mail alert if kafka broker goes down, but it's not working if the kafka broker is down,I didn't get any alerts. If make ==> if(controllerId != null) means when broker is up it's true and getting the mail alert. But i want to get the mail alert only when if(controllerId == null) :

```
 public void checkKafkaBrokerStatus() {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092"); // Update with your Kafka bootstrap servers

            try (AdminClient adminClient = KafkaAdminClient.create(props)) {
                DescribeClusterResult describeClusterResult = adminClient.describeCluster();
                KafkaFuture<Node> controller = describeClusterResult.controller();
                Node controllerId = controller.get(); // Get the current controller ID

                // If controllerId is null, it indicates Kafka is not available or broker is down
                if (controllerId == null) {
                    // Send email alert
                    System.out.println("Kafka broker is down. Sending email alert...");
                    mailService.sendMailAlert();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I tried switching between

```
 if (controllerId == null)==> this won't work and  if (controllerId != null)==> (sends mail alert)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken, I believe Kafka throws an expection instead of returning null when broker goes down.

Modify your code to below and test again

```
public void checkKafkaBrokerStatus() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092"); // Update with your Kafka bootstrap servers

    try (AdminClient adminClient = KafkaAdminClient.create(props)) {
        DescribeClusterResult describeClusterResult = adminClient.describeCluster();
        KafkaFuture<Node> controller = describeClusterResult.controller();
        Node controllerId = controller.get(); // Get the current controller ID

        // If controllerId is not null, it indicates Kafka is available
        if (controllerId != null) {
            System.out.println("Kafka broker is up.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // This block is executed if there is an exception, e.g., broker is down
        System.out.println("Kafka broker is down. Sending email alert...");
        mailService.sendMailAlert();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've just moved the `mailService.sendMailAlert()` in to the exception handler block